# Неиспользуемые слова

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова *подзор*.Как оно образовалось

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, происходит от слова "**зорь/зоръ**", что когда-то означало "*зрение*", согласно словарю Ситникова.  Родственными словами являются "**взор**", "**зоркий**". Некоторые туда же причисляют "**позор**", а также "**зеркало**" и многие другие.  К ним же относятся слова "**зр**ить" (в корень), в**зир**ать.

Термин "*подзорная труба*" имеет отношение к этому слову, я думаю.  Труба эта позволяла увидеть (у**зр**еть) то, что невооружённым глазом увидеть было трудно или невозможно.

Украшение для кроватей, как потом и декоративная отделка карнизов домов, предотвращает возможность обо**зреть**, что находится за ней (т.е. ***под*** кроватью).  Вот оттуда и приставка получилась.